# Autenticação segura via REST

Tags: java, rest, autenticação

Pesquisei e não encontrei solução para o seguinte problema:
*Como faço para controlar as requisições em um determinado serviço REST?*

Por exemplo, se eu tenho um blog no qual acesso meus serviços (inserir post, remover post, atualizar post, por exemplo) da seguinte forma `localhost:80/post/insert/id=1` via aplicação, e se eu digitar isso no browser sem fazer uma requisição via aplicação, vou realizar a inserção do mesmo jeito. Minha duvida é:

Como posso assegurar que meus serviços REST deverão responder apenas a minha aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma alternativa é validar através de tokens. Assim, você pode até mesmo limitar a quantidade de chamadas do seu serviço. Alguns serviços do Google e Bing são limitados a 5.000 chamadas por dia, a partir daí o usuário deve pagar uma assinatura.

Sugestões:

- token com expiração, para evitar chamadas depois de um período de tempo.
- username - controle a nível de usuário.
- IP do cliente - controla a origem da chamada.
- hash da senha - utilizando chaves público/privadas para troca do hash da senha.

Tem mais algumas ideias nos links abaixo:

- [RESTful Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158864/172217)
- [Connect Session Middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html)

Answer (score 5):

Tendo em vista que uma das regras do padrão REST é `Um protocolo cliente/servidor sem estado`, sua requisição deve conter **tudo** o que é necessário para entender o pedido - o que inclui autenticação. Como você faz isso, fica a seu critério. No entanto, posso dizer que é adequado usar, como parâmetros da requisição, um user e um token. Trafegue usando `HTTPS`, sempre, para que os dados sejam encriptados.

Mais sobre o padrão (em inglês) aqui: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Comment: É recomendado/viável enviar o token no _header_ `Authorization`? E por que enviar também o `user`? Além da possibilidade de limitar a quantidade de chamadas ao serviço por um mesmo usuário como sugerido na outra resposta, existe mais algum motivo?